# Creating a jQuery slideshow with captions that show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to this forum and to coding (four classes so far), so I hope you'll bear with me if I seem completely clueless.

My assignment is to create a slideshow of four photos using jQuery. What I'm trying to figure out is how to hide all of my images except the first one, and then get the next image and/or previous image to show when clicking the forward or backward buttons. Then, I need to add text captions on each photo that show/hide upon clicking through each photo.

I'm completely stumped as to how to even begin with creating the jQuery code for this. I've created my HTML and CSS, and that's about it. I've been trying to use [this page](http://code.runnable.com/UfZmYYy6DgF0AAAR/building-a-simple-jquery-slideshow-with-a-few-lines-of-code) as a reference, but am still struggling.

Does anyone have an example of jQuery code that does the above things I mentioned that they would be willing to share to get me started?

Many thanks for your help!

- Jac

Comment: The page you linked seems like a decent starter example; you're reading the comments in the script, right? More general advice: try breaking the problem down into smaller pieces and tackling them one at a time. For example: think about possible ways just to make one image visible. Change its css class? Change its parent's class? Move it in the viewport? Lots of options; you can find examples of them all on places like Codepen.io if you search 'carousel'. As for controls, can you put a button on a page that increments a number when you click? And another one that decrements it? That's a start!

Answer (score 0):

The thing you will need to do will look something like the code I will link below. 
I have done this sort of thing many times and this is the code I have used. If you have any questions please ask or if anyone knows a more effective way please comment as well, I always look to learn as well!

Something like this:

```
 function changeBackground () {
   //Leave the first background alone so that it remains visible.
   $('#bg2').hide();
   $('#bg3').hide();
   $('#bg4').hide();
   var counter = 0;
   function changeOnClick () {
     $('#forward').click(function () { //Code to run when you click forward.
       if (counter === 0) {
         $('#bg1').show();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
         counter = counter + 1;
       } else if (counter === 1) {
         $('#bg2').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
         counter = counter + 1;
       } else if (counter === 2) {
         $('#bg3').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
         counter = counter + 1;
       } else if (counter === 3) {
         $('#bg4').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         counter = 0; //Reset the counter here. 
       } 
     });
     var counter2 = 0;
     $('#back').click(function () { //Code to run when you click back.
       if (counter === 0) {
         counter2 = 3; //Reset the counter here.
         $('#bg1').show();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
       } else if (counter === 1) {
         $('#bg2').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
         counter2 = counter2 - 1;
       } else if (counter === 2) {
         $('#bg3').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg4').hide();
         counter2 = counter2 - 1;
       } else if (counter === 3) {
         $('#bg4').show();
         $('#bg1').hide();
         $('#bg2').hide();
         $('#bg3').hide();
         counter2 = counter2 - 1;
       } 
     });
   };
   changeOnClick(); //Remember to call the function.
};
changeBackground(); //Remember to call the function.
```

Comment: This would work, but it's pretty clunky. Look for ways to reduce how much your code repeats itself - for example, if setting the counter always shows something called `bg[counter number]` (`3` shows `bg3`, `4` shows `bg4`, etc), you don't need to specify what that is every time, right? You can just reference the value of `counter`. You'll have to tweak your selectors, and there's a lot more you can do to optimize this, but start with that and see how it goes.